# Expand <li> so it fits the width of <ul>

Tags: html, css

Before you say this post is a duplicate, it isn't - all the other threads provide instructions on how to make a horizontal `<li>` fit the width of `<ul>` - my question is how to make a **vertical** `<li>` fit the width of `<ul>`.

Below is my code:

**CSS**

```
.ul {
    background: #fff;
    padding: 12px !important;
    font-size: 0;
    width: 125px;
}

.li {
    margin-bottom: 16px !important;
}

.li a {
    font-weight: 300 !important;
    font-size: 22px !important;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul>
<li>
<a href="#">Hats</a>
</li>
```

Currently, I can only click the `li` to the end of the text, but I want the option to select it throughout the complete width of the `ul`.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, but in order to refer to the tags specifically, remove the . in front of your css classes .ul -> ul and .li -> li, as the . refers to a class whereas you're attempting to refer to the tags ul and li

Comment: Thanks, I will do. Basically, the li looks like this - I can only select it where the text is: http://prntscr.com/9qu7ao However I want to select it where the red circle is, as well as the text: http://prntscr.com/9qu7hg

Comment: What if you apply `width:100%;` to `li` element?

Comment: Still doesn't solve the problem

Comment: Just add `display: block` to the `a` element inside `li`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand my comment...

You wanted to find a way for the `<li>` element to fit the width of it's `<ul>` element. But the `<li>` element actually *already is* the full widht of it's parent element (except for the default padding, which can be overriden).

This is due to the fact that `<li>` is by default a `block` element. And block elements take the full width of its parent. Your problem was actually the `<a>` element, which is by default an `inline` element, which *doesn't* take the full width of its parent.

And by modifying the `<a>` from `display: inline` to `display: block`, this actually solves your problem.

Comment: The <a> element is the relevant target.
Set display to block and width to 100%.

Comment: Setting `width: 100%` is not needed. The `display: block` alone will be sufficient as block elements automatically span the width of its parent.